# how to match dot underscore underscore ".__"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all occurences of `.__` with `__` and `.-` with `-` so the following:

`article.__authors.__item`
...would become...
`article__authors__item`

...and...

`bucket.__water.-half`
...would become...
`bucket__water-half`

I started with the `.__` part and came up with `\b\.__\b` as my regex but http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ doesn't seem to like it...

This works for the 2nd match though `\b\.-\b`

Is there a better way?

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: Maybe it's easier to use `str_replace`?

Comment: Post some code, how you are doing this? Are you doing the same in C#? If yes, then use replace method.

Comment: or any replacing function of the unspecified language. Please have a look at the description of the tag you use.

Comment: Have a look at what that flash app you linked to says: "
Matches a word boundary position such as whitespace or the beginning or end of the string.

Note:
The actionscript implementation of word boundaries is very poor."

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, i should've included JavaScript as a tag or made it clear in the question. Thanks for pointing that out. I will try and add the extra tag now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you actually want to do is to remove a dot that is preceded by an alphanumeric character and followed by either a dash or two underscores? Then you can do this using [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

Search for `\b\.(?=__|-)` and replace with the empty string.

If you also want to make sure that another alphanumeric letter follows after the underscores/dash, you can:

Search for `\b\.(?=__(?=[A-Za-z0-9])|-\b)` and replace with the empty string.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick although I ended up using this modified version... \b\.(?=(__|--)(?=[A-Za-z0-9])|-\b)  so it matches .-- as well.

Answer (score 6):

I'd remove the `\b`s unless you want your regex to only match where there is a word boundary.

AS your regex is right now, it would find the pattern in `article.__ authors` but not in `article.__authors` because there is no `\b` between `_` and `a`

It would also fail to find the patern in `.__ authors` because there is no `\b` before the period.

`\.__` would work just fine

The reason it works with your hyphen, is because `_` is considered a legal character for a `word` but a `-` isn't. so `-a` has a word boundary before `a`, but `_a` does not

http://rubular.com/r/cgT1bD7o0d

Comment: Hey - thanks for the answer, very difficult picking which to tick but the 2nd was more complete. I've marked you up though. Cheers.