# String.prototype.replace() to remove dashes and underscores

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all ocurrences of dashes and underscores of a string with `String.prototype.replace()`, but it's not working and I don't know why. My code:

```
var str = "dash-and_underscore";
str = str.replace(/_|\-/, " ");
console.log(str);
```

outputs:

```
"dash and_underscore"
```

in the Chrome console.

Since the `|` acts like the `OR` opperator, what am I doing wrong? I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967503/how-to-match-dot-underscore-underscore/16969686#16969686), but it didn't work, or I'm too dumb to understand - which is an option ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/[_-]/g, " ");
```

`[..]` defines a character class
`g` means *global research*

*(You can write it with a quantifier `/[_-]+/g` to remove several consecutive characters at a time.)*

or

```
str = str.replace(/_|-/g, " ");
```

that is correct too, but slower. Note that the dash doesn't need to be escaped out of a character class since it isn't a special character.

Comment: Oh, facepalm for me... the "global match" flag. Thanks @casimir-et-hippolyte!